# Issue with inputting data in a input string, having that string connect to MS Access on field1, and returning field 2 from that row

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create code where I want a user to input a branch location and I want Python to connect to MS db, find that location, and return from that row the field IpAddress.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\Office List.accdb;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

def WhatOffice():
    print(Fore.BLUE + Style.BRIGHT + "What Office would you like to look up?")
    office_location = input("")
    while office_location == "":
        print(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "Error: You need to enter a Site Name!")
        office_location = input("")
    if office_location in cursor.execute("SELECT IP_Subnet FROM Offices WHERE Office_Code = ?", office_location):
        return WhatOffice
    elif office_location in Lists.quit_list:
        quit()
    else:
        print(Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT + "Error: You need to enter a Site Name!")
        WhatOffice()
```

all i get as an error:

```
What Office would you like to look up?
tu3
Error: You need to enter a Site Name!
What Office would you like to look up?
TU3
Error: You need to enter a Site Name!
```

There is an actual office code field with TU3 in the db

EDIT: Full code here: https://github.com/rb136a/CPS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a hard coded value:

```
office_loc = cursor.execute("SELECT IP_Subnet FROM Offices WHERE Office_Code = hard_coded_val")
print(office_loc)
```

or may be using a tuple:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT IP_Subnet FROM Offices WHERE Office_Code = ?", (office_location,))
```

EDIT:
you should try like this:

```
my_office_list = cursor.execute("SELECT IP_Subnet FROM Offices")
for my_office in my_office_list:
    print(my_office)
```

second your office_varification code is wrong you're comparing two different value...what_office and IP_Subnet
you should do something like:

```
def office_verification():
    param = what_office()
    if cursor.execute("SELECT IP_Subnet FROM Offices WHERE Office_Code = ?", (param, )):
        print(Fore.BLUE + Style.BRIGHT + "Great!")
```

you can also use fetchone().

```
cursor.execute("SELECT IP_Subnet FROM Offices WHERE Office_Code = ?", (param, )).fetchone()
```

always pass parameters as a tuple not as a single parameter and you are calling function 2 times, just little debug your code and try to find error

Comment: **getting it looped?** means...can you please add error logs or full code. are you able to access data with a hard coded value?